# Spacing string in pie chart

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to space my character strings from my pie chart. 
I try :

```
df["pnns_groups_1"].value_counts(normalize=True).plot(kind='pie', fontsize=10)
plt.axis('equal') 

plt.show()
```

Here you can see the picture
[pie chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8k8z.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a legend on the left using direct methods from `matplotlib`. 
Here is an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
       'mass': [0.130,0.130, 0.130, 0.130, 0.190, 0.185, 4.87 , 5.97], 
       'radius': [2439.7,2439.7, 2439.7, 2439.7, 2439.7, 2439.7, 6051.8, 6378.1]}, 
       index=['0_mercury', '1_Mercury','1_Mercury','Mercury', '1_Mercury','2_Mercury', 'Venus', 'Earth'])

patches, _ = plt.pie(df['mass'], startangle=90)
plt.legend(patches, df.index, bbox_to_anchor=(-0.1, 1.))
```

Result:

[image]